# ant to exclude some files

Tags: ant, build

I am trying to use ant to copy files from `sourceDir` to `destDir`, and I also don't want to copy some files, I keep the file names I want to exclude in file: excludelist.txt. How could I implements this is an ant target ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) with nested [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) using nested exludesfile.

From ant manual FileSet :

> excludesfile => the name of a file; each line of this file is taken to
>   be an exclude pattern.

snippet :

```
<target name="foo">
 <copy todir="path/to/destDir">
  <fileset dir="path/to/sourceDir">
   <excludesfile name="excludelist.txt"/>
  </fileset>
 </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I put excludelist.txt in a different directory rather than the sourceDir ?

Comment: Seems the excludelist.txt is in the same level as build.xml..Thanks again.

Comment: Actually the term 'name' of the name attribute name of excludesfile is a bit misleading. In fact it takes a filepath, so you may use <excludesfile name="path/to/your/excludesfile.ext"/> .